# Is it known if "Homotopy type theory" (HTT) can consistently model objects beyond V?

Tags: set-theory, foundations, homotopy-type-theory

I read the free book on HTT but could not find an answer to this question. If that were the case HTT would be stronger than ZFC+LC  (for any choice of  the Large Cardinal axiom). That would be because, ZFC+LC can only reach cardinals below V, and HTT would allow to an infinity taller (larger?) than ZFC+LC because it can in principle put proper classes next to another and mimic the cantor method of using ordinals after $\omega$) to define larger and larger ordinals and cardinals, which, with a simple generalization can be used to measure the sizes of collections of proper classes. 
Is this correct?

Comment: You seem to be confused about something. Homotopy type theory (abbreviated HoTT, by the way) is not really comparable to ZFC. In the presence of certain axioms, the set-theoretic part of homotopy type theory should have the same strength as, say, Mac Lane set theory plus countably many constants interpreted as distinct inaccessible cardinals.

Comment: If you read the HoTT book, what part of your question was not answered by Chapter 10, where set theory is considered and $V$ is exhibited as a higher inductive-inductive type?

Comment: @Bruno: Do we *really* need a specific tag for univalent foundations? Isn't the tag for HTT enough?

Comment: @Asaf Well, one generally does not distinguish them, but [strictly](http://home.sandiego.edu/~shulman/papers/synhott.pdf) HoTT and UF are not identical, though the researchers working on both form a single community. It's just a tag proposal anyway :)

Comment: @Bruno: I think it's a bit too specialized at this moment. So I'm going to remove it if you have no objections.